# how do you create multi time series chart in grafana

Tags: json, grafana, jsonpath

I have this json file:

```
{
  "totalCount": 10,
  "nextPageKey": null,
  "result": [
    {
      "metricId": "builtin:host.cpu.usage",
      "data": [
        {
          "dimensions": [
            "HOST-1234"
          ],
          "dimensionMap": {
            "dt.entity.host": "HOST-1234"
          },
          "timestamps": [
            1642606200000,
            1642606800000,
            1642607400000,
            1642608000000,
            1642608600000,
            1642609200000,
            1642609800000
          ],
          "values": [
            40.86490249633789,
            38.45122528076172,
            38.24514389038086,
            52.10111999511719,
            51.01322937011719,
            40.43871307373047,
            40.392024993896484
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to create multi series timeseries chart using jsonpath. I can extract the xaxis:

```
$.result[*].data[*]['timestamps'][*]
```

and yaxis:

```
$.result[*].data[*]['values'][*]
```

I need to be able to group by dimensions so that I have a different line for each dimensions. How can I do this in Grafana?

[image]

Comment: Did you check for `Group By` Transformation in the Transform tab of the screenshot you provided?

Comment: @AkshayG  I check the group by but I need to be able to extact the "dimensions. Not able to do that per "timestamps". Any ideas? I am basically stuck

Comment: Did you check out this page? https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/basics/timeseries-dimensions/